# Show zero values on line chart for last 4 weeks data

Tags: powerbi, dax

I need help in fixing the line chart. I want to indicate the values in last 4 weeks including if the value is zero as well.

Here is the issue brief.

I have 3 tables.

1. FACT Table - tb_data
2. DATES Table - Tb_dimdate
3. Dummy Date Table - dummydates (which is copy of tb_date and is being used to get x-axis range for last 2 weeks based on Max(Tb_date)
   FACT Table and DATES Table are linked.

[image: tables relationship]

I have created measure to calculate the data in last 4 weeks. Here is the DAX expression.

```
Last 4 weeks Data =
  VAR _maxdate = MAX(tb_DimDate[Date])
  VAR _lastinperiod = DATESINPERIOD(DummyDates[Date],_maxdate,-28,day)
  RETURN CALCULATE(
    SUM(Tb_Data[Value]),
    REMOVEFILTERS(tb_DimDate[Date]),
    KEEPFILTERS(_lastinperiod),
    USERELATIONSHIP(tb_DimDate[Date],DummyDates[Date])
  )
```

[image: line chart result]

The line chart and matrix visual show only dates which have values > 0. I want to include even "0" values.

I have tried both alternate solutions.

1. show items with no data (x-axis)
2. `calculate( if(ISBLANK(sum() , 0 , sum() )`
   and both are not working.

[image]

In both cases the x-axis range changes to all dates instead of just 4 weeks.

Requirement: I need data for 4 weeks including 0 values in line chart.

I have tried working on table relationships and DAX expression but still unable to show 0 values in line chart.

Answer (score 0):

Added `VAR _inRange` to check if date span is in the range. Then on the `RETURN` perform a `COALESCE` on the result.

```
Last 4 weeks Data =
  VAR _maxdate = MAX(tb_DimDate[Date])
  VAR _lastinperiod = DATESINPERIOD(DummyDates[Date],_maxdate,-28,day)
  VAR _result = CALCULATE(
    SUM(Tb_Data[Value]),
    REMOVEFILTERS(tb_DimDate[Date]),
    KEEPFILTERS(_lastinperiod),
    USERELATIONSHIP(tb_DimDate[Date],DummyDates[Date])
  )

  VAR _inRange = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(DummyDates), KEEPFILTERS(_lastinperiod )) > 0
  
  RETURN IF(_inRange, COALESCE(_result, 0), _result)
```